# Why doesn't the style change according to the div size?

Tags: css, dynamic, styles, textfield, contenteditable

I have set some styles on a content-editable div the div is resizable but the style doesn't get change according to the size when the size is changed.
HTML:

```
   <div contenteditable="true" id="input"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#input {
    -moz-appearance: textfield;
    -webkit-appearance: textfield;
    background-color: white;
    background-color: -moz-field;
    border: 1px solid darkgray;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 0 lightgray inset;  
    font: -moz-field;
    font: -webkit-small-control;
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding: 2px 3px;
    width: 398px; 
    height:40px;
    resize:both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give width in percentage, that will help it resize. Dont know if thats what u mean.

http://jsfiddle.net/8xRZv/

```
#input {
    -moz-appearance: textfield;
    -webkit-appearance: textfield;
    background-color: white;
    background-color: -moz-field;
    border: 1px solid darkgray;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 0 lightgray inset;  
    font: -moz-field;
    font: -webkit-small-control;
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding: 2px 3px;
    width: 80%; 
    height:40px;
    resize:both;
}
```